# Flash / AS3 duplicate vars warning in conditional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, conditional-statements

I've written this function in AS3 that converts milliseconds to a readable time format : 00:00:00 (hh/mm/ss).

```
function convertTime(millis:Number):String {

    var Seconds = ((millis / 1000) % 60);
    var Minutes = (((millis / 1000) / 60) % 60);
    var Hours = ((((millis / 1000) / 60) / 60) % 24);

        if ( Math.floor(Seconds) < 10 ) {
            var newSeconds = "0" + Math.floor(Seconds);
        } else {
            var newSeconds = Math.floor(Seconds);
        }

        if ( Math.floor(Minutes) < 10 ) {
            var newMinutes = "0" + Math.floor(Minutes);
        } else {
            var newMinutes = Math.floor(Minutes);
        }

        if ( Math.floor(Hours) < 10 ) {
            var newHours = "0" + Math.floor(Hours);
        } else {
            var newHours = Math.floor(Hours);
        }

    return (newHours + ":" + newMinutes + ":" + newSeconds);
}
```

It all seems to work except the seconds which only ever returns a single digit which I'm sure is relevant to the following :

The flash compiler is throwing up "Warning 3596: Duplicate variable definition" for every instance of the variables set in the else statements?

Am I doing this wrong?

Surely the fact that these are in conditional statements should mean that each variable is only set once right?

Or do I have to be really explicit in AS3 dropping the else(s)? eg :

```
if ( Math.floor(Hours) < 10 ) {
            var newHours = "0" + Math.floor(Hours);
        }

if ( Math.floor(Hours) >= 10 ) {
            var newHours = Math.floor(Hours);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh I found it. AS3 is really strict with var declarations.

The var is already set in the if so no need to re-declare it in the else :

```
if ( Math.floor(Hours) < 10 ) {
            var newHours = "0" + Math.floor(Hours);
        } else {
            newHours = Math.floor(Hours);
        }
```

Comment: var newHours:String should be specified before your if/else block an typed as a String if you add a "0".
Example : newHours = "0" + Math.floor(Hours).toString();

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]

To avoid all those if and else (by using get Timer is suppose), you may use the Date Class instead, and use the [flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html) Class.

To format the output, simply use the [setDateTimePattern()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern()) method.
In your case, use setDateTimePattern("hh:mm:ss"); except if you want to retrieve Milliseconds...

The DateTimeFormatter Class is really useful But there seems to be a problem when you try to get Millisecons("hh:mm:ss:SSS"), so I tried to improve the code to get Milliseconds if You need it.

[EDIT 2]

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeStyle;

var currentTime = new Date();
function getMS():String{
    var ms = currentTime.milliseconds;
    if (ms<10)
    {
        ms = "000" + ms;
    }
    if (ms<100)
    {
        ms = "00" + ms;
    }
    return ms.toString();
}

function formatDate(date:Date) {
    var dtf:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("en,EN");
    dtf.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:");
    var longDate:String = dtf.format(date);
    trace(longDate.toString() + getMS());
    //trace("***LocaleID requested=" + dtf.requestedLocaleIDName);
    //trace("***Format requested (" + dtf.getDateTimePattern() + ")");
}
trace("setDateTimePattern example");
formatDate(currentTime);
// output the current time formated as "hh:mm:ss:SSS"
```

So in this case the output is:

```
setDateTimePattern example
2016-10-23 11:53:32:979
```

[/EDIT 2]

[/EDIT]

Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: For the rants: -1. They do not add anything to the answer, except noise. Without them, this could be a good answer.

Comment: @null I've try to improve the answer and hope that it sounds less noisy.
Sorry, my mistake!
I'm not native English speaking, and wanted to go fast...

Comment: @Grant did you see my answer?
This avoid a lot of loops, and you may use this method to format date objects as you want. The problem is that you may have issues if you want to display the Milliseconds. "MMMM", but there's a workaround to fix it.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you found, this is due to the way AS3 handles variable declarations.  It stems from the AS3 scope model using function-level scope but no block-level scope.  The variable declarations in your code get *hoisted* to the top of the function, equivalent to:

```
function convertTime(millis:Number):String {
    var Seconds = ((millis / 1000) % 60);
    var Minutes = (((millis / 1000) / 60) % 60);
    var Hours = ((((millis / 1000) / 60) / 60) % 24);
    var newSeconds; //Seconds 'if' case
    var newSeconds; //Seconds 'else' case
    var newMinutes; //Minutes 'if' case
    var newMinutes; //Minutes 'else' case
    var newHours;   //Hours 'if' case
    var newHours;   //Hours 'else' case

    if ( Math.floor(Seconds) < 10 ) {
        newSeconds = "0" + Math.floor(Seconds);
    } else {
        newSeconds = Math.floor(Seconds);
    }

    if ( Math.floor(Minutes) < 10 ) {
        newMinutes = "0" + Math.floor(Minutes);
    } else {
        newMinutes = Math.floor(Minutes);
    }

    if ( Math.floor(Hours) < 10 ) {
        newHours = "0" + Math.floor(Hours);
    } else {
        newHours = Math.floor(Hours);
    }

    return (newHours + ":" + newMinutes + ":" + newSeconds);
}
```

So of course you see Warning 3596 for those.

See also http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html for more detail.